# Tree creation using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, binary-search-tree

I will start my question with what I am trying to do. I have an array(nameList) and in my array I am holding objects. These objects consists of names of people(Jack, Jane, James, Daniel, etc) and an array of who these people are related to( Jack is related to Jane and Daniel etc). Of course one person can be related to more than one person but two children cannot be related. I want to keep them in a tree and I want the tree to be according to the relation. I want to start with the person with most relations(For example: Daniel is related to 7 people). I know there could be more than 1 person with the most relations. But for the simplicity of the question I am asking, Lets just say I know who it is and I will pass it in as mostRelated.

[This is just an example of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R29WL.jpg)

This is what I have so far.But i am not sure how to further it.

```
//my array of names is nameList
//to check who they are related to nameList.relatedTo

function Node(names) {
 this.data = names;
 this.parent = null;
 this.children = [];
}

function CreateTree(nameList, mostRelated)
{
 this._root=mostLinked;
  for(var i=0; i < nameList[i].length;i++)
  {
    node= new Node(nameList[i]);
    if(nameList[i].isChecked!)//if already add to the tree
    {
        if(nameList[i].isRelated)//to check if they have any relation
        {
            for(var j=0; i < nameList[i].relatedTo[j].length;j++)
            {
                if(nameList[i].relatedTo.isChecked!)
                 {
                    nameList[i]=Node.parent;
                    Node.children.push(nameList[i].relatedTo[j]);
                    nameList[i].isChecked=true;
                  }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

nameList looks like this

```
nameList
this.name;
this.relatedTo=[];
this.related=false;
this.checked=false;
```

Comment: Using a tree for this is not the right data structure- what if two children are related also? You need to use a Graph / Map

Comment: Your setup is all over the place. Aren't you already establishing who is the parent/child of who? In order to make a graph of your data where your information is already given, you have already made a graph. Give an example of what one element of `nameList` looks like. I might be misinterpreting your goal.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, thanks for the suggestion. But I can make it so that 2 children are not related. I have changed the question.

Comment: @Andrew I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Your question is fundamentally asking for a graph data structure, but it can look like a tree by coincidence.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
  this.relatedTo = []
}


function Graph(familyArr) {
  this._familyArr = nameList.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.relatedTo.length - a.relatedTo.length //reverse sort by relatedTo.length
  })

  const familyObj = {}
  this._familyArr.forEach(({name}) => {
    familyObj[name] = new Person(name) //build object of name-person object key-val pairs
  })
  this.head = familyObj[this._familyArr[0].name] //graphs don't have heads, but they can by 'coincidence'
  this.family = familyObj // actual tree
  this._children = Object.assign({}, this.family) //copies of children to keep proper track of them while building this.family
}

Graph.prototype.addRelative = function(parent, child) {
  this.family[parent].relatedTo.push(this._children[child])
  // console.log(this.family);
  return this
}

Graph.prototype.buildGraph = function() {
  this._familyArr.forEach(parent => {
    parent.relatedTo.forEach(child => {
      this.addRelative(parent.name, child)
    })
  })
}

Graph.prototype.find = function(name) {
  return this.family[name]
}

const john = {name: 'john', relatedTo: ['jane']}
const jane = {name: 'jane', relatedTo: ['john']}
const jack = {name: 'jack', relatedTo: ['andrew', 'jane']}
const andrew = {name: 'andrew', relatedTo: ['jane', 'john']}
const nameList = [john, jane, jack, andrew]


const graph = new Graph(nameList)
graph.buildGraph()

console.log(graph.find('john'))
// Person {
//   name: 'john',
//   relatedTo: [ Person { name: 'jane', relatedTo: [Object] } ] }


console.log(graph.find('andrew'));
// Person {
//   name: 'andrew',
//   relatedTo:
//    [ Person { name: 'jane', relatedTo: [Object] },
//      Person { name: 'john', relatedTo: [Object] } ] }

console.log(graph.head)
// Person {
//   name: 'jack',
//   relatedTo: 
//    [ Person { name: 'andrew', relatedTo: [Object] },
//      Person { name: 'jane', relatedTo: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: This is perfect. More than what I was asking for. Thank you